# Connecting 2 SATA HDD to raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, hard-drive, raid

I'd like to use a Raspberry Pi 4 as an NVR (CCTV camera recorder).

I currently already own two 1.5TB low power SATA Hard Drives which I'd like to use in RAID 1 for redundancy.

The Raspberry Pi 4 does not come as standard any SATA connectors nor is there a trivial way of providing the SATA power connector.

I do not really care about performance, so long as there is enough bandwidth to record the video streams.

So my question is what is the easiest way of getting this configuration to work, if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use USB.

You will need some suitable USB-SATA hard drive enclosures.

I suggest you find enclosures which support external power supplies as trying to power via USB from the Pi will probably not work due to lack of power.

Comment: Since I asked the question I've continued to research the matter and I think you are right. I can get a USB to SATA with external additional input power. Then I'll use `mdadm` to configure the raid array (the OS will run of micro USB). USB is fine as speed ins't important and once its setup I won't be plugging in and unplugging the drives. Thanks :)